# xCode breakpoint not show my code while debug

Tags: xcode6, xcode6.1

[image]

xCode6.1.1 breakpoint showing like this, cant debug line by line. how to change the settings.

Comment: Show some courtesy and accept the correct answer.

Answer (score 30, accepted):

debug -> debug Workflow  -> always show Disassembly (uncheck).

Comment: Thanks to you Alex, I had messed up since a long with this. Wasn't sure whats happening. Your answer gave it right hit :)

Comment: save my life, I checked that by don't know any senses.

Comment: Saved my life. Thanks.